# Visual studio XML comments. UNC path to document instead of http link to webpage

Tags: c#, unc, xml-comments

When commenting my code, I know that I can link to a webpage like this:

```
/// <Refer url="http://microsoft.com/foo/bar.aspx"/>
```

But is it possible to reference an excel document (for example) on a samba share? ie.:

```
/// <Refer unc="\\server.mydomain\share\document.xls"/>
```

Comment: You can put anything there that you want. In what context are you asking? A help file generator? You'll probably just need a `file://` URL.

Comment: Over the last 3 months, I have written a lot of related classes that I'm assembling into a class library so that my colleagues can use it as a dll. I'm trying to add comments to properly explain the source code but also make it possible to generate a help file at some point. Sandcastle looks like the popular option for such, but I've never used a help file generator. Is there one built in to VS 2012?

Comment: This seems to do what I was looking for, but I'd like to know how to click the link when it appears in the mouseover tooltip in VS. 
/// Refer to <href url="file:/\\server.mydomain\share/doc.xls">Metadata Reference Table 1v34</href> for more.